# Brightness issue in Waveshare 10.1 inch Capacitive Touch Screen

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen

I have 10.1 inch Touch screen displays (10.1inch HDMI LCD (B) 1280×800, IPS)
https://www.waveshare.com/10.1inch-hdmi-lcd-b-with-case.htm

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with Android Things OS and Pi is connected to this display.
In one display, When I attach touch cable on the display, the brightness of this display goes down automatically. I have changed the cable, changed the Pi but the problem still persists.

Power Supply for display- 5V 2.5A Adapter
Power Supply for RPI- 5V 2.5A Adapter

Can anyone please tell me the reason for this issue and how can we resolve this.
Awaiting your reply.

Thanks and Regards
Sugandha Sharma

Comment: Who knows... You have not given any information about the screen, model Pi, Power supply, kernel and OS version. And have you tried just swapping the screen (using the same Pi, PSU,etc)? Please update your question with relevant informaton

Comment: @Dirk I have connected other screen with the same Pi and it is working but previous screen is not working.

Comment: So using a different, but the same type of screen works? Then I would say there is something wrong with that screen. Of course, it could also be a marginal power supply. I would also suggest trying a 'reference system' using current Raspbian (Lite) and current kernel

Comment: This type of screen works. But after a period of time in some screens brightness issue happens.